# call getting stuck at std::map erase function

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to understand in which scenario the std::map erase function can gets blocked and not able return from erase.

```
{
    popHttpRequest(uint64_t requestId)
   {
    boost::unique_lock<boost::shared_mutex> uniqueLock{ m_HttpRequestTableMutex };
    auto itr = m_HttpRequestTable.find(requestId);
    if (itr != m_HttpRequestTable.end())
    {
     auto request = itr->second;
     m_HttpRequestTable.erase(itr);
    }
}
```

Comment: `erase` would run destructors of the key and the value. Perhaps one or both are classes whose destructors take locks, and end up in a deadlock.

Comment: The easiest way to resolve this is to run it in a debugger.  When it gets "blocked" - pause execution, and go start looking at the stack trace.  You should be able to look at the thread doing the erase and find out pretty quickly if it's unable to get a mutex lock.

Comment: (gdb) p m_requestTableMutex
$1 = {state = {shared_count = 0, exclusive = true, upgrade = false, exclusive_waiting_blocked = false}, ......  , this is after calling unique_lock and execution proceeded till  erase, it gets blocked there .  is this still lock issue? . before calling unique_lock the value of exclusive found to be false.